# can ng-hide invoke a function in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

My table looks like this, with more than one tbody:

```
  <tbody>
    <tr class='group-header' ng-click="collapseDetail($event)"> ... </tr>
    <tr class='detail' ng-hide="groupIsCollapsed()">...</tr>            
    <tr class='group-footer'> ... </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class='group-header' ng-click="collapseDetail($event)"> ... </tr>
    <tr class='detail' ng-hide="groupIsCollapsed($event)">...</tr>            
    <tr class='group-footer'> ... </tr>
 </tbody>
```

In my `collapseDetail()` function I toggle a class `collapsed` on the `tbody`.

And so I would like to have the detail row hidden only if the parent tbody hasClass('collapsed`).

Is that legal?  What I have isn't working:

```
$scope.collapseDetail = function (e) {
   var targ = angular.element( e.currentTarget );

   $scope.$apply( function(targ){
      targ.parent().toggleClass('collapsed');
   });
}

$scope.groupIsCollapsed = function (e) {
  if (e == undefined) return false;
     var targ = angular.element( e.currentTarget );
       return targ.parent().hasClass('collapsed');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a neater solution had to work on creating a directive for you, as over here you require an isolated scope on individual tbody, so that they can show/hide the detail.

Using **Angular Directive** has many advantages like

> 1. having isolated scope (as mentioned above)
> 2. Reducing html markup
> 3. NO DOM manipulation in controller ( a strict no taking angular perspective into account, all DOM manipulations to be done only in
>      directive making it more maintainable)

HTML Code:

```
<table>
    <tbody rendered key="assasa" val="tgtrtghrt"></tbody>
    <tbody rendered key="fsfgsd" val="teeger"></tbody>
</table>
```

Controller Code for this question:

```
angular.module('t', [])
//You can see that nothing is in the controller now
.controller('test', function ($scope) {});
```

Directive Code:

```
.directive('rendered', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            key: '@',
            val: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var ele = "<tr ng-init='collapseTbody = false;' class='group-header' ng-click='collapseTbody=!collapseTbody'><td>{{key}}</td></tr><tr class='detail' ng-hide='collapseTbody'><td>{{val}}</td></tr>";
            scope.$watch('key', function () {
                element.html(ele);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        },
    }
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ynbncyv/)**

More on **[Angular Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**

Comment: Thank you. Is the key/value code an essential part of this solution? I am trying to puzzle it out.

Comment: yeah .. as in the fiddle you can see that key would be the heading which when clicked can expand and give the value...